# Calling soap web service does not return data on Samsung Android 6.0.1 devices. But on other devices it works fine

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have a news app,  which when starts fetches news items from server with Asynctask. The webservice is a .net soap webservice(.asmx). Everything works fine on other devices and Android 6.0.1 even on Android 6.0.1. It seems that, Webservice is called, progressbar is displayed and next web method is also called,  but no data comes back. 
We have discovered it on only Android 6.0.1 devices like Samsung Note and Samsung S6/s7.

Comment: debug your app and post your logcat

Comment: Are you requesting the appropriate permissions at runtime?

Comment: actually it is working fine on other devices except Samsung Note/S6/S7.